# How to correct for periodic errors in data set (worm motor)

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, data-analysis

I have a monochromator produced by Bentham which I am using for my physics experiment. This runs through the wavelengths in steps of what I thought were exactly 1nm. To calibrate the monochromator I used an ocean optics spectrometer and recorded the wavelength produced at a number of wavelengths. However after conducting the experiment I found that the not only is the monochromator systematically off at differing wavelengths, it also demonstrates a sinusoidal  characteristic. I have been told that I am not allowed to calibrate the monochromator itself manually, so instead have to shift the dataset systematically. If the data was systematically offset I would be able to calibrate this while relative ease I would assume by just shifting the wavelength values as dictated by the straight-line fit. However as shown there is an added periodic error on top of the basic straight line one. After conducting some research I have found that this periodic error is demonstrated by worm motors which don’t step by the same distance the same time. However I have only seen it related to worm motor in telescopes and how to stabilise them  and not how to systematically adjust for this error on a data set.

**TLDR**

Essentially my question boils down to how to correct for the periodic error caused by my worm motor on my data set. How do I figure out by what factor to shift each one?

[image]

The first graph shows the difference in the recorded wavelength and the wavelength that the Bentham monochromator believes it is outputting. It demonstrates a linear error in combination with a periodic one.

[image]

The second graph show the residues from a different data set but with the same problem. IO just couldn't find the first data set to produce the residuals for.

Comment: Just a hunch, since the error look sinusoidal enough, you could simply try to fit it by a function of the type A Sin($\omega$ t+$\phi$), where you would optimize A, $\omega$ and $\phi$ to minimize least squares. Is that not something you can do  (for instance, in mathematical using this built-in function https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html)

Comment: This is one of those things that Fourier analysis is good for. If you Fourier transform the data, you can see the power spectrum, larger spikes will appear at places where a sinusoidal trend appears in the data. You can use this to find the equation of your periodic variation (similar to the above comment by Frotaur).

Comment: Sorry if my missing something but even if I plot a sinusoidal wave over it how would it correct for the worm motor error. The problem is that my wavelengths are wrong because my computer thinks the steps are 1nm each time when the worm motor is moving at a different rate